# Programmatically adding view to StackView not doing anything

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have two vertical stack views, one nested within the other in the following fashion:

```
StackView #1
   UITextField
   StackView #2 (nothing in this one)
   UIButton
```

I am trying to programmatically insert UITextFields into my StackView #2, but when I do, nothing happens. I see no view getting inserted and nothing happens in screen.

StackView #1 is set to Alignment Fill, Distribution Fill Proportionally. And my StackView #2 is both Fill.

I get no constraint warning when I try to add to StackView #2 so I'm curious as to why nothing is happening. Here is how I add:

```
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 285, height: 30))
textField.placeholder = "Name"
subtasksStackView.addArrangedSubview(textField)
```

Comment: I tried recreating this and it works fine for me. What constraints are you using on the various views?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that you can add to a Playground. It contains the same structure as the structure in your question, but there is a slight difference; I also use a third stack view, which is just used to wrap everything so that I can place the content at the top of the view controller without any unwanted resizing (stretching, shrinking) of the contained elements. I suspect that it may be a constraint issue, but this should help you compare your current implementation with a working solution.

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let mainStackView = UIStackView()
    let stackViewOne = UIStackView()
    let textFieldOne = UITextField()
    let stackViewTwo = UIStackView()
    let buttonOne = UIButton(type: .system)

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        // mainStackView is used so that the UI elements can be displayed at the top of the stack view without being stretched to fill the entire view controller.
        mainStackView.axis = .horizontal
        mainStackView.alignment = .top
        mainStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(mainStackView)
        // mainStackView needs constraints to the view controller's view.
        mainStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        // Configure the first stack view. This is StavkView#1, in your case.
        stackViewOne.axis = .vertical
        stackViewOne.alignment = .fill
        stackViewOne.distribution = .fillProportionally
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(stackViewOne)
        // Configure the first text field.
        textFieldOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        textFieldOne.placeholder = "Text Field One"
        textFieldOne.borderStyle = .line
        stackViewOne.addArrangedSubview(textFieldOne)
        stackViewOne.addArrangedSubview(stackViewTwo)
        // Configure the button.
        buttonOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        buttonOne.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        buttonOne.tintColor = .black
        stackViewOne.addArrangedSubview(buttonOne)
        // Add the second text field to the nested stack view. This is StackView#2, in your case.
        let textFieldTwo = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 285, height: 30))
        textFieldTwo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        textFieldTwo.placeholder = "Name"
        textFieldTwo.borderStyle = .line
        stackViewTwo.addArrangedSubview(textFieldTwo)
    }

}

let viewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```